# What do I ask previous programmer for in web maintenance takeover?

Tags: web-development

I am taking over the maintenance of a simple commercial website, images and information are displayed.  I have experience with html, php, word press, javascript, java, and such.

What should I ask the previous dev for when it comes to taking over the maintenance, hosting, files, testing, deployment, etc? Also how much should I charge to maintain and expand the site?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Brad's answer, I would ask for

- All administrator accounts and passwords, or have new ones created for you (once you're comfortable with the site, make sure to review all accounts for security reasons)
- Documentation of environments, deployment process, etc.
- A list of any recurring tasks or maintenance items that are required to perform

and, most importantly, ask the previous developer politely if you can contact him should you have any questions. If they push back on that, try to put a limited time frame for contact, like 4 to 6 weeks or something, or come to an agreement on pay if you happen to need him.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask him honestly - where are the dirty hacks, the tar pits, the things that he is uncomfortable with.